# laravel valet not works after php8 upgraded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, php-8

I just upgraded brew ..

```sh
brew update // or brew upgrade ..
```

and suddenly php 8 has installed on my macbook.

After that, Laravel valet does not work..

I wonder if I have to remove php8 and reinstall php 7.x .

Or maybe I can get how to fix this situation..

Usually Laravel 7/8 is used.

Anybody can help this ?

Comment: Are you on the latest version `valet on-latest-version` check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade valet (`composer global upgrade`)
Then re-run the install scripts (`valet install`)

Comment: Good.. this is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks!